# Adding moment.js timezone in Angular project with angular cli - webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, momentjs

I need to add moment.js and a timezone build in an Angular project using angular cli / webpack.

I imported in the ts files the moment-timezone

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

I configured the `angular.json` file with the scripts I need

```
{
  "projects": {
            ..
        "styles": [],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
          "node_modules/moment/locale/es.js",
          "node_modules/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js",
          "node_modules/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js"
            ]
...
}
```

This it's partially working but I have two issues:

- It's not adding `moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js`
- When I check which files where added in `vendor.js` I find all moment and moment-timezone folders included

I don't want the full folder is being added to vendor.js. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean "I don't want the full folder is being added to vendor.js"?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem.

`import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';`

added everything from `moment-timezone` and `moment` to the bundle, that means every locale and every timezone.
What i did was to import just the things i needed:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone/moment-timezone';
import 'moment/locale/sk';
import { MomentInput } from 'moment';
```

I also added static initializer for my DateUtils and copied the timezone data for my timezone from the timezone build, because i only wanted one timezone:

```
static initialize(): void {
  moment.locale('sk');
  moment.tz.add([
    'Europe/Prague|CET CEST|-10 -20|010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010|-2aFe0 11d0 1iO0 11A0 1o00 11A0 Qrc0 6i00 WM0 1fA0 1cM0 16M0 1lc0 1tA0 17A0 11c0 1io0 17c0 1io0 17c0 1fc0 1ao0 1bNc0 1cM0 1fA0 1a00 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1cM0 1fA0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00 11A0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 WM0 1qM0 11A0 1o00 11A0 1o00|13e5'
  ]);
  moment.tz.link('Europe/Prague|Europe/Bratislava');
  moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Bratislava');
}
```

In whole app only `DateUtils` now imports `moment` stuff, so nobody should import whole bundle by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

To use moment.js in Angular, install moment.js first:

```
npm i moment --save
```

then import moment.js where you need:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Now you could use moment as in other JavaScript projects:

```
moment().format();
```

Comment: Unforutnately this doesn't solve the OP's question. The question is about "moment-timezone" not "moment"